# Is it safe to use hidden inputs to retrieve user data?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, codeigniter

I have a very large form divided into 5 subforms. When you go from form1 to form2, the information in form1 is stored in DB and a userId is created. Then in form2 this userId is added as a hidden input. Something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="userIDnumber" id="userId" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo base_url();?>" id="url" />
    //form data
    <input type="button" id="prevButton" value="Prev" />
    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

If user decides that wants to go back to form1 to edit data, when clicking 'back' button the following happens:

```
        var prev = document.querySelector('#prevButton');
        if(!prev.addEventListener){
            prev.attachEvent('onclick', prevPage);
        }else{
            prev.addEventListener('click', prevPage, false);
        }

        function prevPage(e){
            var userId = document.getElementById('userId').value;
            var url = document.getElementById('url').value;
            var form = document.createElement('form');
            form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
            form.setAttribute('action', url + 'form/1');
            form.style.display = 'hidden';

            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            input.setAttribute("name", "userId");
            input.setAttribute("value", userId);

            form.appendChild(input);
            document.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();              

        }
```

What I'm doing is creating a hidden form and in this form adding a hidden field with the UserId, so that when going to form1 I can retrieve the data the user just posted and update database if user changes anything.

My question is, is this a safe way to retrieve user data? I'm very new at javascript, so I'm not sure if doing things like this there's a way for an attacker to access other user's data by directly inserting their id.

If so, what is the correct safe way of doing it? I thought of maybe using sessions, but the client I'm working for doesn't want the user having to log in.

I haven't found any questions related to this, but if there are I apologize and please kindly point me to where it is.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: An id is just a number so unless an attacker has access to your database that number is pretty meaningless.

Comment: Then you can generate some per-user secret key and use it in form submission.

Comment: @edhedges You still probably don't want anyone being able to specify any id and messing up some user's data (even if the attacker doesn't gain anything).

Comment: The thing about "hidden" inputs is they're not really hidden. Anyone who knows how to do a view-source can see the contents of them. So whether they're "safe" or not really depends on what data they contain.

Comment: this is what $_SESSION is for, assign the userId there and/or validate against it

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store the incomplete data in your session and after all forms are completed validate the data and send it to the database?

Comment: I would suggest that you just store the forms data into sessions that way it will be available to all other form pages.

Comment: @Cthulhu creating a random unique key is a very smart idea, didn't thought of it. Thanks!

Comment: I thought user need to log in in order for session to work, I think I'm wrong. I will look more into that, thank you for suggestion.

Comment: @Ant100 Yes. Your wrong. The purpose of session isn't just login. The session variables are used for transferring data to multiple pages. It can hold other data along with users login details.

Comment: @JayBhatt I did what you suggest, I have a question though, is data from session erased when you refresh page?

Comment: @Ant100 Nope. The data stays. Unless yo unset it using session_unset() and session_destroy().

Comment: @JayBhatt And is this way safer? or is there a way anybody could access the data stored in session?

Answer (score 0):

When the user access my web page, I create a global object in which I create a user namespace like this:

```
APP.user = {};
```

In this object you can store the properties that you need and you can retrieve user data from the server with Ajax when the user logs in.

You get a simple object with key-value pairs in the browser memory. Eg:

```
APP.user = {
    user_id: 'kgy', 
    firstname: 'kim', 
    lastname: 'gysen', 
}
```

Actually, this data is also publicly available.
Storing data in the DOM / global object space is never safe when it concerns sensitive data.
Of course, the user needs to be logged in to access these data anyway.

One thing is that this approach would be faster, as there is no need to crawl the DOM, just to get some local user data across different pages.

Comment: but user must login for this to be safe?

Comment: The object just stores user data after you logged in as a user. This is useful if you need the data across different forms / pages. You won't need to make a request to the server each time, because the data will be stored at the client.

Comment: ah ok! problem is client doesn't want user to login, he wants anybody being able to fill the form without login

Comment: But how can you store a user id at the client if the user has not logged in? That moment, the user id is not known yet...

Comment: When user fills first form, an id is created. So if he is at second form, he already has an id at database, which is the one I use to retrieve data already filled. If anything changes I update data.

Comment: Well, then you can store the id in the way I mentioned. You can set a status of for example: logStatus which could be true/false. This is safe in the sense that only the current user will have access to this data.

Comment: @Ant100 its safe because the data is stored on the server. Still the security will depend on your server.